# Integration PowerBI x Snowflake x AzureAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, powerbi-desktop, multi-factor-authentication

In general, I have a big problem with the correct synchronization of 3 things that are in the subject line. The most important problem is - logging in PowerBI Desktop via Microsoft account.

[PowerBI Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm609.png)

I wonder if there is a step-by-step instruction to make it all work.

Unfortunately, when logging in directly through Snowflake, with every action I am told to accept the MFA and it is terribly annoying.
Another option, is if you can get around accepting MFA every now and then in powerbi.
So can something be changed in Snowflake?

1. i did everything according to this and this instruction
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/snowflake-tutorial

And everything is laughing logging in through AzureAD works correctly and there is no problem.

2. another thing that I did is this:
   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-azure.html

Well, and here, unfortunately, too much did not change.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-powerbi.html

Comment: Still the same problem :/